# htmlentities works different when changing php version

Tags: php, utf-8

i have a problem with **htmlentities** in one of my websites. I get form database a utf8 encoded string, but **when i use htmlentities it returns an empty string**.

After some testing I determined that the root of the problem is the php installation. ¿Why? Because if i change my php version with the Nginx config (sites-available file...) it works.

In my "PHP Version 5.6.35-1+ubuntu14.04.1+deb.sury.org+1" installation it works correctly, but in "PHP Version 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.22" in doesn't work. The database is the same, the files are the same, all is equal besides php version.

Some tensting code:

```
$text = "señal";

mb_detect_encoding($text); //returns 'UTF-8'

htmlspecialchars($text); //returns ''

htmlentities($text); //returns ''

htmlentities(utf8_encode($text)); //returns  'SE&Ntilde;AL'
```

Is something on the php configuration that i need to see? Thanks!!!

Comment: It's not the version, see https://3v4l.org/qSbSJ . I'm not sure what setting it would be, though.

Comment: There was a change the default encoding of htmlentities in 5.6.0. Maybe that's the issue.

Comment: `$text = señal` Really? That is a compile error of course

Comment: @RiggsFolly Sorry, i fixed the code.

Comment: [*"5.6.0 The default value for the encoding parameter was changed to be the value of the default_charset configuration option."*](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php)